# Prevent scaling when height of window is adjusted OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

The problem that I am having is I have a window that I am using a perspective view on. I need the graphics in this window to not scale at all on any resize. Ideally I would like my graphics to stay exactly where they are in the center of the window and not change size or skew at all. I have a bunch of different positions on the scene that I need to calculate if someone is clicking inside of and the position and size of these images changes with each resize. I have managed to work around the width resizing with the following code

```
void resizeWindow(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight)
{
    GLdouble aspect = (GLdouble)newWidth / newHeight;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glViewport(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}
```

However, when I adjust the size of the height the image auto scales. Is there something short of forcing a resize of the window everytime a user resizes the height that I can do to prevent the user from doing that? Is there a better way of going about the mouse click detection or the scene setup altogether?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto scales"?

Comment: Pro-Tip: Never set viewport and projection in the window resize handler. The OpenGL viewport and projection may be changed at any time, also during rendering a single frame. So if there are certain elements in your display, that should occupy a specific number of pixels wide/high at a certain pixel offset in the window then the best approach is to do this by adjusting the viewport for just these elements.

Comment: Almost perfect daten. I have removed the viewport and perspective from the resize function but when I resize the height, instead of it pushing the bottom up towards the image it pushes the image into the top. Is there any way to avoid this? Instead of being able to bring the bottom to the pic it pushes the picture into the top until the image is too high to appear on the window.